# Match, update and replace values from one dataset to another in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have two datasets, one has old data and one has updated data. I'd like to create a new dataset by updating values based on if the area, date and column values match.

**Data**

df1

```
area    date        aa  bb  cc  
japan   10/1/2027   1   0   0   
us      1/1/2022    5   5   5   
fiji    11/2/2026   1   1   1
```

df2

```
area        date        aa  bb  cc  stat
japan       10/1/2027   0   5   5   yes
fiji        11/2/2026   0   0   10  no
```

I have two datasets. I wish to **replace the values in [aa], [bb], and [cc] columns of df2 with the updated values from df1 if we have the same date and area values**. The aa, bb, and cc column are replaced with the updated values.

**Desired**

```
area        date        aa  bb  cc  stat
japan       10/1/2027   1   0   0   yes
fiji        11/2/2026   1   1   1   no
```

**Doing**

```
df['date'] = df.date.apply(lambda x: np.nan if x == ' ' else x)
```

I am not exactly sure how to set this up, however, I have an idea. Any suggestion is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using .[merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and making sure date columns in both dfs are set to datetime.

```
df1["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df1["date"])
df2["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df2["date"])

df3 = pd.merge(left=df1, right=df2, on=["area", "date"], how="right").filter(regex=r".*(?<!_y)$")
df3.columns = df3.columns.str.split("_").str[0]
print(df3)

    area       date  aa  bb  cc stat
0  japan 2027-10-01   1   0   0  yes
1   fiji 2026-11-02   1   1   1   no
```

Comment: thank you @Jason Baker this works! one question- how do I turn the output back as a dataframe? It seems to be different from the original format

Comment: It's still a dataframe. Can you explain what you mean by different? If you print(type(df3)) you'll get <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

Comment: Seems unnecessarily complex and difficult to generalize if column names have underscores ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and [`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html):

```
cols = ['area', 'date']
out = (df2[cols].merge(df1, on=cols, how='left')
       .combine_first(df2)[df2.columns]
      )
```

output:

```
    area       date  aa  bb  cc stat
0  japan  10/1/2027   1   0   0  yes
1   fiji  11/2/2026   1   1   1   no
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this can possibly be simplified to:

```py
output = df1[df1['area'].isin(df2['area']) & df1['date'].isin(df2['date'])]
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
area        date        aa  bb  cc  stat
japan       10/1/2027   1   0   0   yes
fiji        11/2/2026   1   1   1   no
```

**Even when df1 looks like this:**

**DF1**:

```
    area       date  aa  bb  cc
0  japan  10/1/2027   1   0   0
1     us   1/1/2022   5   5   5
2   fiji  11/2/2026   1   1   1
3   fiji  12/5/2025   9   9   9
```

Comment: thank you @ScottC, would this account for the time as well? The time and area both have to match

Comment: OK - Lynn - I think this should work now.